# Why calling Dispose() on BinaryReader results in compile error?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class which uses BinaryReader internally and implements IDisposable.

```
class DisposableClass : IDisposable
    {
        private BinaryReader reader;
        public DisposableClass(Stream stream)
        {
            reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
//                reader.Dispose();// this won't compile
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
        }
    }
```

I have already figured out that I need to cast BinaryReader to IDisposable to be able to call Dispose on it, but I don't understand why I can't just call the Dispose() method directly without casting to IDisposable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work because the `Dispose` method on `BinaryReader` has been explicitly implemented.

Instead of being implicitly implemented, as in:

```
public void Dispose()
{
}
```

...it has been explicitly implemented, as in:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
}
```

...which means it can only be accessed via the `IDisposable` interface. Therefore, you have to cast the instance to `IDisposable` first.

Comment: Perfect example of why you shouldn't deviate from the standard Dispose pattern.

Comment: Or just call BinaryReader.Close() which does the same thing.

Comment: Even so, if you implement a Close() method, it should do the work normally done in Dispose() and Dispose() should simply call Close(). No matter what, BinaryReader didn't follow the pattern properly.

Comment: @Scott - true enough. Oddly, the MSDN docs state that Dispose is only to be used internally - which lead me to believe that Close did extra work. But, Reflector shows that Close and Dispose are equivalent. Seems like it could be cleared up in the future without back-compat concerns....

Comment: @Mark, You are correct, the docs do state "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." which is even further reason to say it's not following the pattern.

Comment: There are very few cases where Close and Dispose are not equivalent (mostly in the ADO.NET classes in order to deal with connection pooling). It does seem like something that could be fixed without back-compat concerns, but it's doubtful it will ever change.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222996/why-calling-dispose-on-binaryreader-results-in-compile-error#223020), the `BinaryReader` class does not properly implement the Dispose pattern.

Looking at this class in Reflector, it looks like this (for .NET 3.5):

```
public class BinaryReader : IDisposable
{
    public virtual void Close()
    {
       this.Dispose(true);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       if (disposing)
       {
          Stream stream = this.m_stream;
          this.m_stream = null;
          if (stream != null)
          {
             stream.Close();
          }
       }
       this.m_stream = null;
       this.m_buffer = null;
       this.m_decoder = null;
       this.m_charBytes = null;
       this.m_singleChar = null;
       this.m_charBuffer = null;
   }
   void IDisposable.Dispose()
   {
      this.Dispose(true);
   }
}
```

The problem here is that by making `IDisposable.Dispose()` an explicit interface implementaiton it forces a developer to call `Close()` instead of `Dispose()`.

In this context, we have a case of imbalanced semantics. There was never a call to "Open" the reader so it is not intuitive to "Close" the reader.

Going one step further, in order to call Dispose() you must then explicitly cast to `IDisposable`, which is not something you ordinarily need to do. You do have the option of calling `Dispose(bool)` directly, but how do you know what the boolean parameter should be?

To properly follow the pattern, it should have been implmented as:

```
public class BinaryReader : IDisposable
{
    public virtual void Close()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
       if (disposing)
       {
          Stream stream = this.m_stream;
          this.m_stream = null;
          if (stream != null)
          {
             stream.Close();
          }
       }
       this.m_stream = null;
       this.m_buffer = null;
       this.m_decoder = null;
       this.m_charBytes = null;
       this.m_singleChar = null;
       this.m_charBuffer = null;
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
      this.Close();
   }
}
```

This would allow you to call either `Close()` or `Dispose()`, in which case either call continues to result in calling `Dispose(true)`. (This is the same flow as the actual implementation by calling `Close()` or `((IDisposable)reader).Dispose()`).

Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on which way you choose to look at it) because `BinaryReader` does implement the `IDisposable` interface it is allowed in a using statement:

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(...))
{
}
```

Comment: "You do have the option of calling Dispose(bool) directly" - it's protected, so that's not an option.

Comment: @Mark, your comment contradicts itself...Dispose(bool) is protected so it's not directly accessible unless you inherit from BinaryReader, which might be an option in this case depending on the usage.

Answer (score 1):

Actually they have chosen to use Close() instead of Dispose()
Dispose has been explicitly implemented. Which is why you can't see it.

However Close does the same thing as dispose and this is the method they want you to use. Reflector gives the following disassembly for the Close method

```
public virtual void Close()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
}
```

Close() is used because it is a better choice of words in the context of a binary reader.

Comment: Any ideas why they went down this path?